# Tiles 2.2.2 AttributeTagSupport removed ?

Tags: tiles

So in previous versions of tiles 2.1.4 you used to be able to extend TagSupport classes

```
public class TilesInsertAttributesTag extends AttributeTagSupport {
```

Etc etc ...

These classes seem to be removed in 2.2.2 / 3.0.5 but I can't find any reference as to why (they weren't marked deprecated) and to what solution is preferred now

Answer (score 0):

they are auto generated now.
take a look at the Tiles AutoTag project and tags and macros for the different scripting languages are now automatically generated.